# Get which key pressed from (keypress) angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

Is it possible to find out which key was pressed when using (keypress) in Angular 2?

E.g.

```
<input type=text (keypress)=eventHandler()/>

public eventHandler() {
    //Some code
    console.log(keyPressed);
}
```

Edit: Seems my naming conventions were a bit off. I did not mean AngularJS 2, I meant Angular 2.0 with typescript.

Comment: are you using angularjs?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Pass `$event` to your event handler.  The `$event` is a DOM [KeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent).

```
<input type=text (keypress)="eventHandler($event)">

eventHandler(event) {
   console.log(event, event.keyCode, event.keyIdentifier);
}
```

If you know which KeyboardEvent property you want, you can pass that into your event handler:

```
<input type=text (keypress)="eventHandler($event.keyCode)">

eventHandler(keyCode) {...}
```

Comment: this does not detect all events. for example not arrow keys or escape. but you can use (keydown) to get all of them.

Comment: event.key seems to be the one to use now, it gives a string like '0', 'a', 'ArrowLeft', etc. Using event.keyCode discouraged.

Comment: function AvoidSpace(event: any) {
    var k = event ? event.which : window.event.keyCode;
    if (k == 32) return false;
}

Above is the code i've used to prevent user from entering spaces in input box. I am implementing this in angular2. I am getting an error over keycode, saying "Property 'keycode' does not exist on type 'Event'.
any". What should i do?

Comment: if u want to detect backspace ..etc use keydown

Comment: Thank you, Mark, for another accurate, concise answer.  Your contributions to StackOverflow have helped me time and time again.

Answer (score 19):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'key-up3',
  template: `
    <input #box (keyup.enter)="onEnter(box.value)">
    <p>{{value}}</p>
  `
})
export class KeyUpComponent_v3 {
  value = '';
  onEnter(value: string) { this.value = value; }
}
```

Or use like this..

```
 <input #box (keyup.enter)="onSubmit(form.value)">
 <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">
```

Comment: Nice solution. No need to check key codes etc in component.

Comment: I was going to write the same answer. I found this usage here. https://alligator.io/angular/binding-keyup-keydown-events/

Answer (score 5):

Based on the comment made on the answer:

> this does not detect all events. for example not arrow keys or escape. but you can use (keydown) to get all of them.

The best solution to get all events both backspace and delete or whatever key, just use (input)

```
<input type=text (input)="eventHandler($event.keyCode)">

eventHandler(keyCode) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

**2020 Update:**

`event.keyCode` is deprecated and you should use `event.code` instead (just check for browser compatibility first)

```
<input type=text (keypress)="eventHandler($event)">

eventHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
   console.log('Key pressed is:', event.code);
}
```

Deprecation of event.keyCode:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

`event.code` browser compatibility:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code#Browser_compatibility