# Prevent user from firing space in a textbox

Tags: angular, typescript

Previously, I dealt with the problem using jQuery as follows:

```
$("#textInput").keydown(function (e) {
  return e.which !== 32;
});
```

How would you approach it with the new Angular and Typescript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get which key pressed from (keypress) angular2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34157705/get-which-key-pressed-from-keypress-angular2)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Or simply ;

```
<input type="text" (keydown.space)="$event.preventDefault();">
```

---

---

I managed to create a handy directive which accepts what ever key number you give it and prevents them

```
@Directive( {
    selector : '[prevent-keys]',
    host : {
        '(keydown)' : 'onKeyUp($event)'
    }
} )
export class PreventKeyseDirective {
    @Input( 'prevent-keys' ) preventKeys;
    onKeyUp ( $event ) {
        if ( this.preventKeys && this.preventKeys.includes( $event. keyCode ) ) {
            $event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like

```
 <input [prevent-keys]="[32, 37 , 38 , 39 , 40 ]" type="text">
```

This will prevent space , up , left , down , right keys :D

Comment: what does this mean `(keydown.space)` ? @Milad please add some explanation

Comment: What about ALT+32? You can still enter space by pressing ALT and typing 32...

Answer (score 6):

You should use event binding in your template like this:

```
<input type="text" (keydown)="keyDownHandler($event)"/>
```

Then in your controller define the `keyDownHandler()` function:

```
keyDownHandler(event: Event) {
    if (event.which === 32)
        event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In component you should implement this method .

```
onKeydown(event) {
if (event.keyCode === 32 ) {
  return false;
}
```

}

After that,In HTML tag,

```
<input type="text" class="form-control col-md-10" placeholder="First Name" (keydown)="onKeydown($event)" [value]="firstName" #newFirstName>
```

Comment: What exactly your answer adds to the existing ones in the thread, for instance [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41375216/3345644) one?

Comment: this answer I very interesting, because I really don't know how can "return false" work.

Answer (score -1):

i just decalre `$` on the top of my class like this

```
 declare var $: any;
```

than you are able to use `$` in your code as you explained

```
$("#textInput").keydown(function (e) {
  return e.which !== 32;
});
```

Otherwise there are various methods in angular2 like `keyup` and `keydown` and so on you can use those also

Comment: This is not a good solution. Mixing jQuery and angular is not good practice. There are so many easier ways to do this as the other answers have provided.

Comment: @ChrisKooken I understand man, but at the time of answer written there were not so many ways to achieve this as compared to today :) 
Moreover I provided answer as per the question asked.