# How can I restrict input to a text-box so that it accepts only numbers and the decimal point( atleast 4 decimals e.g 192.168.192.192)?

Tags: angular, validation

I need to restrict input field so that it doesn't accept characters and special symbols. Only accept numbers and 2 or more decimal or period(.).

Note *Even cannot type characters in input field.

html:-

```
<mat-form-field>
                <input matInput onkeypress="return isNumberKey(this, event);" placeholder="JNDI Name" formControlName="jndiName" [(ngModel)]="body.jndiName" autocomplete="off">
              </mat-form-field>
```

ts:-

```
isNumberKey(txt, evt) {

    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode == 46) {
        //Check if the text already contains the . character
        if (txt.value.indexOf('.') === -1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        if (charCode > 31
             && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I want a input field in which I can type numeric and period(.) at least 4 dots in that field but I don't want to my form field to accept characters or special symbols. It will accept only and only numbers and dot(s).

Comment: are you looking for [ip address validation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44176289/5621827)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [HTML input pattern](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp).

> The pattern attribute specifies a regular expression that the  element's value is checked against on form submission.

For IP validation you can use this regular expression : `^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)`

**Edit**:
In order to ignore any other keys than the one you want you can use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41375142/prevent-user-from-firing-space-in-a-textbox).

```
@Directive( {
    selector : '[allow-keys]',
    host : {
        '(keydown)' : 'onKeyUp($event)'
    }
} )
export class AllowKeysDirective {
    @Input( 'allow-keys' ) allowKeys;
    onKeyUp ( $event ) {
        if ( this.allowKeys && !this.allowKeys.includes( $event. keyCode ) ) {
            $event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

It is a more "angular-like" way to handle ignoring keystrokes than the one I described in my comment. I created an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b2qf8e?embed=1&file=src/app/AllowKeys.directive.ts) to demonstrate its use.

Comment: It's not working as per my requirement. It accept IP address pattern but it also accept characters. What I want , If I type characters  in input field it will not display in field.. Like input type= number works. We cannot type any characters in input field.

Comment: @NishaYadav In order to ignore a typed character you just handle the onkeypress event of the input and return false when the keycode of a character you dont want to be typed matches the keycode of the event. I am commuting right now and I will update my answer shortly.

Comment: @NishaYadav I edited my answer. See if this works for you.