# Trigger the keyboard event (enter key) in angular4

Tags: javascript, angular

In my application I have a global search field which is used to filter the data in the list , list will have multiple column. From other component setting the filter value (setting to input value) it's happening but I have to trigger the manual keyboard event (enter key) action on the input.

I tried with viewChild decorator.

> component.html

```
<input #gb type="text" placeholder="Global search.." class="changeListComponent_inputSearch"  [(ngModel)]="jiraRef" />
```

> component.ts

```
@ViewChild('gb') gb:ElementRef;         
this.jiraRef =  jiraRef;
const event = new KeyboardEvent("keypress",{ "which ": "13"});
this.gb.nativeElement.focus();
this.gb.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);
```

using this I could set the value and make a focus but keyboard event is not triggering.

Comment: by changing the event to `const event = new KeyboardEvent("keypress", { key: '13' }  );` it worked for me. That assuming that you perform your actions when your view is already instantiated. Could you provide more detail or better yet a stacklitz with your code? :)

Answer (score 0):

Triggered the  key up event using the native js code.
Placed the id attribute to the input element along with element reference.

> Created the new function from inside my component.

```
triggerEvent(el, type) {
    if ('createEvent' in document) {
        var e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
        e.initEvent(type, false, true);
        el.dispatchEvent(e);
    } else {
        var e = document.createEventObject();
        e.eventType = type;
        el.fireEvent('on'+e.eventType, e);
    }
}

var el=document.getElementById('gb-search');
this.triggerEvent(el,'keyup');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are making it complicated. why not just add a keypress event to the input field, and then also be able trigger that event through a viewChild?

```
<input id="text1" type=text (keyup)="enterPressed()">
```

and then also be able to access this same method through a view child:

```
this.viewChild.enterPressed();
```

Answer (score 0):

In general your inputs can be like:

```
<input (keydown.enter)="doEnter()">
```

From other component simply call to the function `doEnter`. How?

If the search component is in the parent it's easy because you can use ViewChild

```
 <search-component></search-component>
 @ViewChild(SearchComponent) searchComponent
 ..whe we need..
 this.searchComponent.doEnter()
```

Else, typical use a Subject to subscribe. You has a service,

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class KeyBoardService {
  keyboard:Subject<any>=new Subject<any>()
  constructor() { }

}
```

In your component Search, inject the service in constructor and in ngOnInit

```
constructor(private keyboardService:KeyBoardService){}
ngOnInit(){
    this.keyboardService.keyboard.subscribe(_=>{
         this.doEnter()
    })
}
```

And in the other component

```
constructor(private keyboardService:KeyBoardService){}
..in anywhere..
this.keyboardService.next(null);
```

Exist another option that is when the two components are at time in the screen -and in the same `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` that is use a template reference variable and a Input. So we has

```
<search-component #search></search-component>
<other-component [search]=search><other-component>
```

in other component

```
@Input('search') searchComponent
..in anywhere
this.searchComponent.doEnter
```

Answer (score -4):

You can simply use

```
<input type=text (keypress)="eventHandler($event)">

eventHandler(event) {
   console.log(event, event.keyCode, event.keyIdentifier);
}
```

Solution is based on this answer
[Get which key pressed from (keypress) angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34157705/get-which-key-pressed-from-keypress-angular2)

Comment: I have to trigger the keyboard event programmatically

Comment: yes you have to bind the keypress event so that everytime you press a key, the event will trigger.

Comment: not for the manual event key press , from javascript code i have to trigger the enter key on the text box.